# How to stop a sound (while its playing) from another method

Tags: java, android, swing, concurrency, inputstream

I have some music playing in my program. I want it to switch music depending on certain actions etc. The problem is I have my music begin playing from one method and I am trying to stop it from another method or action event. The other method isnt able to find my clip object because it is not public. Is it possible to make this clip object public for my whole class? I tried making another class just for music. Could someone guide me? Thanks,

```
public void playsound(String filepath){
    try {
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filepath));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip( );
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start( );    
            }

        catch(Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
}


 public void dummyMethod(){

//when this method is call make the clip stop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make the `Clip` object an instance/class-wide variable instead of just a local variable, so you can call a `clip.stop()` or `clip.pause()` method when you want to turn it off or pause it?

**EDIT**

```
// declare as an instance variable
private Clip clip; 

public void playsound(String filepath){
    try {
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filepath));
            // NOTICE: I am only initializing and NOT declaring (no capital Clip)
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip( );
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start( );    
            }

        catch(Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
}

 // call stop method to stop clip form playing
 public void dummyMethod(){
    clip.stop();
 }
```

Comment: How do I do this? If I write 
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip( );
It doesnt recognize it as an object. How is the object declared?

Comment: See my edit. You just declare `clip` outside of your method then you initialize it how you did before.

Answer (score 0):

Make  `Clip clip` a class variable then call the `clip.Stop()` from dummyMethod

Comment: What would be an example of clip as a class variable?
Clip clip = new Clip(); ?

Answer (score -1):

Declare your **Clip**  variable  outside the methods,
Just write *Clip clip;* above your methods,