# Music in Java (pause/stop)

Tags: java, playback, audio-player, javasound, pause

I am trying to play music in my app. I am able to play when i click on Play button but not able to stop the music when i click on stop button please help look into this code and point out the issue.

```
   private Component crearPanelMusica() {
             JPanel panel = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());

    //start buttom
            bMusicaStart.setIcon(musicaStart);
            bMusicaStart.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 50));
            panel.add(bMusicaStart);
            bMusicaStart.addActionListener(this);

    //Stop buttom
            bMusicaFF.setIcon(musicaFF);
            bMusicaFF.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 50));
            panel.add(bMusicaFF);
            bMusicaFF.addActionListener(this);
            return panel;
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369365/how-to-stop-a-sound-while-its-playing-from-another-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest moving Clip object to a Class field and using method Clip.stop(); to stop it when button is pressed